# Array data flickers when one item is changed in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my React Native app, i am rendering an array and i have toggle buttons set in that page. If i change any one item, the array gets changed and the component rerenders which result in flickering of the component. How can i just change the item that's needed to be changed and stop the flickering.

Here's my current component:

```js
const Notifications = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { t } = useTranslation('setting');

    const notificationStatus = useSelector(getNotificationModeSelector);

    const setNotificationStatus = useCallback(
        (value: any) => dispatch(notificationsActions.setNotifications(value)),
        [dispatch],
    );
    const getNotificationStatus = useCallback(
        () => dispatch(notificationsActions.getNotifications()),
        [dispatch],
    );

    const onToggleNotification = useCallback(async (item) => {
        var changeParam = notificationStatus.map(obj =>
            obj.id === item.id ? { ...obj, enabled: obj.enabled ==='1' ? '0' : '1' } : obj
        );
        setNotificationStatus(changeParam);
    }, [notificationStatus, setNotificationStatus]);


    useEffect(() => {
        getNotificationStatus();
    }, []);

    
    console.log('Notifications Page',notificationStatus );

    return (
        <DesktopContainer>
            <Container>
                {notificationStatus.length !== 0 && notificationStatus.map((item)=>{
                    return(
                        <Wrapper key={Math. floor(Math. random() * 100)}>
                            <Title>{item.name}</Title>
                             <Switch
                                onColor={styles.SWITCH_COLOR}
                                offColor={styles.MEDIUM_GRAY}
                                isOn={item.enabled === '1' ? true : false}
                                size={
                                    Dimensions.get('screen').width > styles.MIN_TABLET_WIDTH
                                        ? 'large'
                                        : 'medium'
                                }
                                onToggle={()=>onToggleNotification(item)}
                            />
                        </Wrapper>
                    )
                })
                }
               
            </Container>
        </DesktopContainer>
    );
};

export default memo(Notifications);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on this line:

```js
<Wrapper key={Math. floor(Math. random() * 100)}>
```

Your `key` should always be a fixed value.  If your `notificationStatus` item has a unique ID, that's ideal.  React optimizes its render cycle by using these keys; that's what allows it to only change what it needs.  Since all of your mapped components have new keys on each render, React re-renders them all.

See the "Picking a Key" section of this tutorial for more.  https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html